# Control multiple element widths with individual sliders

Tags: jquery

I m trying to control the width of multiple elements with a slider. What's the best way to do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/WQbsW/

```
<ul>

<li id="text-1">1<div id="slider-vertical" style="height: 200px;"></div></li>
<li id="text-2">2<span id="slider-vertical" style="height: 200px;"></span></li>
<li id="text-3">3<span id="slider-vertical" style="height: 200px;"></span></li>
<li id="text-4">4<span id="slider-vertical" style="height: 200px;"></span></li>
<li id="text-5">5<span id="slider-vertical" style="height: 200px;"></span></li>
<li id="text-6">6<span id="slider-vertical" style="height: 200px;"></span></li>

</ul> 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 0,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
    $('#text').css('width', ui.value + '%');
          //$("#text").text(ui.value + '%');   
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: First of all : you should not put multiple DOM element with the same id (ie: here, slider-vertical)

Comment: In addition to what @ddr2 said; use css classes instead.

Comment: I can't seem to understand properly what you want : do you want one slider which controls the width of all your `li` ? or an independent slider for each one ?

Comment: damn ... I was tired last night. I was using duplicate ids. I got it working. I ll post a fiddle once I work out all the bugs. And I wanted  an independent slider for each element.